# Greasemonkey for Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, browser-addons, safari

Is there a way to get one of the Greasemokey implementations for Safari working in Snow Leopard? Most of them seem to rely on the Input Managers, and they seem to have broken or something with Snow Leopard.

Comment: FWIW Input Managers are incompatible with 64-bit applications and were marked as deprecated with 10.5 and so with 10.6 they don't work with most applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this :

1. Install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) (the latest version is updated for 10.6)
2. Install [Greasekit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/) (please download GreaseKit 1.6 using the [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/greasekit/) link)
3. Run Safari in 32-bit mode (might not be needed for the latest SIMBL and GreaseKit versions).

[image]

There you go, GreaseMoney on Safari.

Comment: This, sadly, does not work. Scripts never seem to 'add' themselves

Comment: @joshhunt: it works, but it depends on the plug-ins/scripts themselves whether they are 64bit compatible. Reverting safari back to 32-bit should solve it. I have SIMBL/GreaseKit/BetterGMail running right now.

Answer (score 2):

Coming in late with updated info correcting the above:

- SIMBL 0.9.7a and above are Snow Leopard compatible.
- SIMBL is no longer an Input Manager and now lives in /Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax